# How do I get the latest Firebase and Firepad version from Firebase cdn?

Tags: firebase, firepad

The firebase CDN does not appear to have an API or a "latest" tag. The suggestion is:

```
<script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.2.9/firebase.js"></script>
```

A quick google shows that different sites have a lot of different version loading. I know I forget to update when I am forced to ask for a specific version.

The question is how can I infer the versions for firebase.js and firepad.(js|css) from a browser request?

---

Some examples...

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general we recommend just picking the latest version and using it.  We don't provide a "latest" version that you can include.  This insulates you if we ever accidentally introduce a bug or change a behavior that you rely on.

Then if/when you want to upgrade, you can do so and make sure everything still works before releasing it to your users. People tend to do the same thing (pin their app to a specific version) with jQuery and other libraries.

Comment: Hi @MichaelLehenbauer.  Thanks for Firepad.  Briefly, it's frustrating I can't find out what is the **latest version of firepad** at the moment!  Where actually on what page or resource does it state the latest version?  There's a vague rumour that it is 1.4.0  :)  Truly appreciate it if you can take a sec to answer this, thank you!

Comment: For example, if U click [here](http://smhk.com/notes/) you'll see some frustrating minor problems.  Checking on Safari.  This for july 2016.  I'm trying 3.2.0/firebase.js, 5.17.0/codemirror.js (the latest - it states the latest version on their web site), and 1.4.0/firepad.css  :O

Comment: BTW it beseeches me to say .. 'Firepad is brilliant"  But you hear that all the time  :)

Comment: Sorry, I haven't had much time to devote to firepad lately.  You can check the releases page to confirm that 1.4.0 is the latest: https://github.com/firebase/firepad/releases  As for the safari issues, please open a github issue (or better yet send a pull request with a fix :-)).

Comment: got it @MichaelLehenbauer, the URL you just gave does the trick!  thanks again for firepad !